# select max version over several fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I got a table like this :

```
value   | version1 | version2 | version3
--------|----------|----------|---------
     aaa|         1|         1|        1
     aaa|         1|         1|        2
     aaa|         1|         2|        1
     aaa|         1|         2|        2
     aaa|         3|         1|        1
     aaa|         3|         2|        1
     aaa|         3|         2|        2
     bbb|         1|         1|        1
     bbb|         2|         1|        2
     bbb|         2|         2|        1
     ccc|         2|         1|        2
     ccc|         3|         1|        1
     ccc|         3|         2|        1
     ccc|         3|         4|        1
```

What I want to do, is write a query that only selects the last record. With one version field it's easy to do with just a max function, but how can I do this with 3 version fields?

In this case, the "version1" field has the highest priority and "version3" the lowest, logicaly "version2" is in the middle. For example, a version1 with a value of 2 always has priority over a version3 with a a value of 10 when his version1 is 1.

So in above table, I want to select the following records :

```
 value   | version1 | version2 | version3
 --------|----------|----------|---------
      aaa|         3|         2|        2
      bbb|         2|         2|        1
      ccc|         3|         4|        1
```

first look at the highest version1, then the highest version2 and then the highest version3.

Can someone please tell me what the most efficient way to do this is?

thx in advance!

Comment: last record is not in first table

Comment: correct, cause that would made it harder to explain

Comment: I'm sorry, what exactly are you asking? perhaps edit the number so they are all different to illustrate where they come from unless they are references to each other.

Comment: is your desired result from firs table: `aaa, 3, 2, 2`?

Comment: @TabAlleman It itsn't really sel-contradictory. Op wants the last row in his/her sample because the last 2 rows there have the same value for `Version1` and `Version2`, but the last row has the highest `Version3`, hence it should be selected. But if there was another row with a value for `Version1` of `4`, then that one should be returned. Anyway, I also agree that LittleSweetSeas has the correct answer for the question as written. I do think that op wants to choose one row per different value of the `value` column though, making user2315555's answer the correct one

Comment: @TabAlleman I read the first revision and don't think it was contradictory since op was talking about discerning the last 2 rows, it was badly explained though

Comment: Looking back at it, I now agree.  It was so badly written at first that I misunderstood OP's intent, but I see now what it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited:

Looking at your further explanation, you need to partition your output per different value.
You can then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, limiting the output to just one row per different value.

Example:

```
SELECT 
   value, version1, version2, version3
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY value 
        ORDER BY version1 DESC, version2 DESC, version3 DESC
      ) RN,
      value, version1, version2, version3
   FROM tableName
) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` function will give an incremental number to each row of the result set,
while `PARTITION BY` clause will give an independent row number for each set of different values.

`ORDER BY` works by sorting your records using the first value declared (version 1), then skipping to second value in case of exact match of first value, and so on...
`DESC` keyword indicates to sort from higher to lower value.

Applying the final `WHERE` condition does the magic: just the top row for each different value is returned.

Comment: So please elaborate a bit: looking at your question, this answer would provide a good solution

Comment: Works great, I was able to alter this and expand the number of fields in the value part. Thanks for helping! @LittleSweetSeas

Answer (score 3):

This might help you :

```
select value,version1,version2,version3
from 
(
  select *,row_number() over(partition by value order by version1 desc, version2 desc, version3 desc) as rn
  from yourtable
) as t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx)** to partition the data over the `value` field and specify the ordering on the columns as required. Using this method, you are effectively ranking the rows in order with a row number per value group, and you can simply take the rows where the row number = 1 per value:

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1897b/1)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Versions
    ([value] varchar(3), [version1] int, [version2] int, [version3] int)
;

INSERT INTO Versions
    ([value], [version1], [version2], [version3])
VALUES
    ('aaa', 1, 1, 1),
    ('aaa', 1, 1, 2),
    ('aaa', 1, 2, 1),
    ('aaa', 1, 2, 2),
    ('aaa', 3, 1, 1),
    ('aaa', 3, 2, 1),
    ('aaa', 3, 2, 2),
    ('bbb', 1, 1, 1),
    ('bbb', 2, 1, 2),
    ('bbb', 2, 2, 1),
    ('ccc', 2, 1, 2),
    ('ccc', 3, 1, 1),
    ('ccc', 3, 2, 1),
    ('ccc', 3, 4, 1)
;
```

**Query using ROW_NUMBER()**:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    value ,
                    version1 ,
                    version2 ,
                    version3 ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value 
                                        ORDER BY version1 DESC, 
                                                 version2 DESC, 
                                                 version3 DESC ) AS RowIdentifier
          FROM      dbo.Versions
        ) t
WHERE   RowIdentifier = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1897b/1/0)**:

```
| VALUE | VERSION1 | VERSION2 | VERSION3 | ROWIDENTIFIER |
|-------|----------|----------|----------|---------------|
|   aaa |        3 |        2 |        2 |             1 |
|   bbb |        2 |        2 |        1 |             1 |
|   ccc |        3 |        4 |        1 |             1 |
```