# Return Rows with MAX Rev values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL statement to return all rows with the latest quote revision from a table. For example a query on the table below

```
Quote    QuoteBase  QuoteRev
2500-01    2500       01
2600-01    2600       01
2600-02    2600       02
2600-03    2600       03
2700-01    2700       01
2700-02    2700       02
```

I would get the following results

```
Quote   QuoteBase   QuoteRev
2500-01    2500       01
2600-03    2600       03
2700-02    2700       02
```

I have tried the following statement but did not work for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM [QuoteTable]
GROUP BY Quote
HAVING QuoteRev = MAX(QuoteRev)
```

Comment: can you specify it more clearly how your data looks in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, limiting the output to just one row per different value.

Example:

```
SELECT 
   Quote, QuoteBase, QuoteRev
FROM (
   SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY QuoteBase
        ORDER BY QuoteRev DESC
      ) RN,
      Quote, QuoteBase, QuoteRev
   FROM tableName
) T
WHERE RN = 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` function will give an incremental number to each row of the result set,
while `PARTITION BY` clause will give an independent row number for each set of different values, ordered by the values set in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Applying the final `WHERE` will return just the top row for each different value in QuoteBase.

Comment: Just answered a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888691/select-max-version-over-several-fields/26888759#26888759

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Quote ORDER BY QuoteRev DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

SELECT Q1.* 
FROM QuoteTable Q1
Inner Join QuoteTable Q1s on Q1s.Quote = Q1.Quote And Q1s.QuoteRev > Q1.QuoteRev
Where Q1s.Quote IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this by grouping the values and taking max condition

```
declare @t table (Quote varchar(20),Quotebase INT,QuoteRev VARCHAR(3))

    insert into @t (Quote,Quotebase,QuoteRev)values 
    ('2500-01',2500,'01')
    ,('2600-01',2600,'01'),
    ('2600-02',2600,'02'),
    ('2600-03',2600,'03'),
    ('2700-01',2700,'01'),
    ('2700-02',2700,'02')


    select MAX(Quote),Quotebase,MAX(P.QuoteRev)QuoteRev
     from 
       (select Quote,
    Quotebase,
    QuoteRev,
    MAX(SUBSTRING(Quote,0, CHARINDEX('-',Quote)))R
     from @t
    GROUP BY Quote,
    Quotebase,
    QuoteRev)P
    GROUP BY Quotebase
```